# How to set editor always active in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, rich-text-editor

Code for `<p:editor/>` component with rich text editing capabilities.

```
 <h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <p:editor id="faqResponseId" 
              converter="textConverter"                                                                                 
              value="#{product.currentFaq.faqResponse}">
    </p:editor>
  </h:panelGroup>
```

The editor always gets active when I am clicking on the editor body.

How to make the `<p:editor/>` Active by default in Primefaces ?

Note:When I drag some text and drop in the editor It is not active and the added text is not setting to backing bean.When the editor is active only, the value is setting to backing bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that p:editor is deprecated. It was replaced with p:textEditor and it would suit your needs. From what i can see, it is always active, exactly what you asked for :)

Link to the demo on primefaces showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am using PF6.0 this is introduced in PF6.0.6 So I have to use latest now to use `<p:textEditor>` in our application.But Is there any solution specific to PF6.0  ?

Comment: Actually, I think there should be a solution for the p:editor also, somewhere in the CSS. I don't have access to some code, or the primefaces 6.0 library right now, but you could try and check the state of the editor when it is clicked, and change it's CSS so it matches the same state always